# Which console commands get flagged as suspicious?

Tags: torchlight-2

Title says it all. If it's not done by simply flagging certain commands how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["Most" of the console commands](http://forums.runicgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=34590) in game will mark you as a suspicious player as confirmed by Adam Perin from Runic. There doesn't appear to be a more specific list available.

In addition, if you have been flagged, it is not apparent to you - only to other players you're playing with online. In the instance you have been flagged, your characters' name plate will be preceded by a red **!**.

A full list of console commands [can be found here](http://pastebin.com/0hThmpzJ).

Comment: Wouldn't the lack of access to the shared stash for that character indicate that it had been flagged? Or is that a separate effect of some console commands?